# Child shell getting variables from parent

Tags: shell, export, scope, parent, wrapper

I have  a  Wrapper that creates a shell script which it will execute within the wrapper itself 
In the wrapper I have sourced my variables.  The child  script created by the wrapper has all variables expanded while it is being created with the exception of the username and password which I intentionally do not want to expand .
So lets see this below

```
# this is my wrapper 
source /pathtofile
# barrage of command , check conditions  and functions ....
echo "db_loader $para1 $para2 \$user \$pass " >> child.ksh
```

so my child.ksh will look like this

```
  # child.ksh
    db_Loader P1 P2 $user $pass
```

When I execute child.ksh within the wrapper. The user and pass do not expand run time so you see the blanks there

```
 +db_loader P1 P2 ' ' ' '
```

and obviously errors

Why can the child.ksh grab the parents variables- run time  ( since its executed within the parent ) . Any work -around on this .

Comment: Are the variables in your source file preceded with the word `export`? I.E. `export user=xxx; export pass='abc'`? They need to be. you must export a variable for it to be visible to child processes. Good luck.

Comment: Yes of course . The filename I have does the export

Answer (score 0):

duhh. I derived some variables within functions and those were'nt preceded by export. That fixed it 
TY Shellter